# How do I fix the error "was not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++, linux, function, unix

The system is:  Linux/[CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.4

I keep getting an error for functions not declared in scope. Is it not legal to call a function within another function? I read an article on function, thought it was because I needed to declare the functions void when I call them, but I received new errors. I am not sure if I need to declare them global or something.

> client.cpp:32: error: 'takef' was not declared in this scope

> client.cpp:33: error: 'putf' was not declared in this scope

> client.cpp: In function 'void takef(int&)':

> client.cpp:44: error: 'testa'  was not declared in this scope

> client.cpp: In function 'void putf(int&)':

> client.cpp:70: error: 'test' was not declared in this scope

Example of the type of code I'm trying to implement:

```
sem_t mutex;
sem_t S;
char buffer[1024];

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

/*
    void signal_callback_handler()
    {
        close(sockfd);

    }
*/

void father(int &sockfd)
{
    while(1)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int ms = rand() % 2000 + 5000
        send(sockfd, DATA, strlen(DATA), 0);
        usleep(1000*ms);
        takef(sockfd);
        putf(sockfd);
    }
}

void takef(int &sockfd)
{

    /*
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */

    testa(sockfd);

    /*  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void testa(int &sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void putf(&sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    test();
    test();
    sem_post(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    father(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declare them before they are used.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['foo' was not declared in this scope c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283168/foo-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix. Move the function definitions above the void father() function.

In code

```
sem_t mutex;
sem_t S;
char buffer[1024];

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

/*
    void signal_callback_handler()
    {
        close(sockfd);

    }
*/

void takef(int &sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */

    testa(sockfd);

    /*  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void testa(int &sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void putf(&sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    test();
    test();
    sem_post(&mutex);
}

void father(int &sockfd)
{
    while(1)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int ms = rand() % 2000 + 5000
        send(sockfd, DATA, strlen(DATA), 0);
        usleep(1000*ms);
        takef(sockfd);
        putf(sockfd);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    father(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Or another alternative, like mentioned below, is to write a function prototype. This is similar to how one would write a prototype for functions in a header file and then define the functions in a .cpp file. A function prototype is a function without a body and lets the compiler know the function exists but is not defined yet.

Here is an example using prototyping

```
sem_t mutex;
sem_t S;
char buffer[1024];

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

/*
    void signal_callback_handler()
    {
        close(sockfd);

    }
*/

// Prototypes
void takef(int &sockfd);
void testa(int &sockfd);
void putf(&sockfd);

void father(int &sockfd)
{
    while(1)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int ms = rand() % 2000 + 5000
        send(sockfd, DATA, strlen(DATA), 0);
        usleep(1000*ms);
        takef(sockfd);
        putf(sockfd);
    }
}

void takef(int &sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    testa(sockfd);

    /*  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void testa(int &sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
}

void putf(&sockfd)
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    test();
    test();
    sem_post(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    *
    *
    *  *Other code*
    *
    *
    */
    father(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or write prototypes for them.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you need to declare the functions before they are used.
Include the prototype of the functions before you start defining any of the functions.